# Should I cast size_t to ptrdiff_t?

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable, ptrdiff-t

I have a malloc'ed array of pointers that forms a hash table. To step through the hash table I'd use pointer arithmetic, eg:

```
node_t ** tc = table;
size_t tcs = sizeof(node_t *);
for(long i = 0; i < tableSize; tc+=tcs, ++i) { 
    // Do some stuff with *tcs location in the table.
}
```

Question is should I cast the `size_t` returned by `sizeof()` to `ptrdiff_t` for correct addition in the increment part of the `for` condition? or does it even matter for addition?

Comment: Since you are already using an index,`i`, you could just as well avoid the pointer: `for(long i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {  tc = table+i; ...}` Or : `{ tc = &table[i];}`

Comment: OT: You should make `i` a `size_t`.

Comment: Actually, what is the effect you expect from doing `tc += tcs`?  Because I fear it might not do what you hope for it to be doing.

Comment: To cut it short: `tcs` is useless here. Just do `++tc` to go to the next array item.

Comment: @alk That's why I've asked.  Because it seems plausible to me that the OP wants the effect of `++tc` (equivalent to `tc += 1`) but – unless running on an extremely bizarre platform where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(node_t *)` – his code will do something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `ptrdiff_t` here as there is no pointer difference around.

What you probably want is:

```
for (node_t ** tc = table; tc < (table + tableSize); ++tc) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `ptrdiff_t` for handling negative values. `size_t` handles positive values, such as the result of `sizeof` in your example, so you do not need a cast.

With this said, the code looks suspicious: C compiler factors the size of the `struct` into your pointer arithmetics, so the fact that you have to add `sizeof(node_t*)` to a double-pointer to `node_t` is probably a mistake. If you want to advance to the next pointer in an array of pointers, add `1` to the current value of that pointer. The compiler is smart enough to multiply that `1` by `sizeof(*ptr)` for you, based on the type of the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

No. You don't need to.

Pointer arithmetic is performed based on the *type* of the pointer `T *`. Adding a `size_t` will not affect the pointer arithmetic as the increment is done using `sizeof(T)`.

To quote the standard (C11 draft):

**6.5.6 Additive operators**

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
>   In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
>   array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
>   (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
>   i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
>   the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
>   and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element
>   of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
>   operator that is evaluated.

On the other hand, casting `size_t` to `ptrdiff_t` could lead incorrect code as `ptrdiff_t` is a signed while `size_t` is an unsigned type. So if the resulting value is larger than what `ptrdiff_t` can hold then there's a problem. In short, pointer arithmetic is well-defined when adding any integral type to a pointer type and you don't need such a cast at all.